# How long after PhD Major Revisions sign off

Tags: phd, exams

I got the result of major revisions following my second viva, and completed these changes, to resubmit a third time. Is anyone able to indicate the typical length of time for sign off following submission? The thesis went back to the examiner.

I have contacted the relevant administrative bodies to be told to wait. It's almost been a month.

Cheers

Edit: I'm in the Southern hemisphere (winter)

Comment: If your school is in summer vacation period, I think you'll have to wait a little longer than usual.

Comment: Southern hemisphere

Comment: This seems too variable to allow for a good answer. It'll depend on your examiner's schedule and level of care, on the details of your revisions, and on what's allowed at your institution. Googling about this, it's easy to find anecdotal experiences ranging from a couple of days to over three months... Your best bet is probably to [apply for jobs while you wait](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8595/17254).

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question per se (as I guess no other than the assessment committee can). But I can add my personal anecdote :)
At my University there is a general rule of 2 months assessment time (1st handin). But for me after about 1.5 month I got a mail saying that the Ph.D. School of my university forgot to send my thesis to the assessers.

In general I would suggest that revision should not take more than 2 months.